# Hints to perform this definite integration

Tags: definite-integrals

I stumbled upon this integration $$\int_0^a \left(x-\sqrt{a^2-x^2}\right)^3\,dx.$$ And I have no idea on how to proceed with it. It would be very helpful if someone would provide me with some hints. Thank you.

Comment: Did you try with $x=a\sin t$.?

Answer (score 1):

After the substitution $x=a\sin t$ we are left with
$$ a^4\int_{0}^{\pi/2}(\sin t-\cos t)^3 \cos(t)\,dt =a^4\sqrt{2}^3\int_{0}^{\pi/2}\sin^3\left(t-\frac{\pi}{4}\right)\cos(t)\,dt$$
that equals
$$ 2a^4\int_{-\pi/4}^{\pi/4}\sin^3(t)\left[\cos(t)-\sin(t)\right]\,dt = -4a^4\int_{0}^{\pi/4}\sin^4(t)\,dt$$
since the integral of an odd, integrable function over a symmetric interval is zero.
The last integral is elementary and leads to 
$$ \int_{0}^{a}\left(x-\sqrt{a^2-x^2}\right)^3\,dx = \color{red}{\frac{8-3\pi}{8}\,a^4}.$$

Comment: Sorry, $\int_{0}^{a}\left(x-\sqrt{a^2-x^2}\right)^3\,dx = \color{blue}{\dfrac{8-3\pi}{8}\,a^4}$.

Comment: @MyGlasses: thank you, now fixed.

Comment: @JackD'Aurizio I have one last question. Can you explain this step of yours.$a^4\int_{0}^{\pi/2}(\sin t-\cos t)^3 \cos(t)\,dt =a^4\sqrt{2}^3\int_{0}^{\pi/2}\sin^3\left(t-\frac{\pi}{4}\right)\cos(t)\,dt$

Comment: @AyanShah: I am exploiting the formulas for $\sin(\theta\pm\pi/4)$ and $\cos(\theta\pm\pi/4)$ and, at last, the substitution $t\mapsto t+\pi/4$.

Comment: @Jack D'Aurizio In the last step when you integrate $-4a^4\int_{0}^{\pi/4}\sin^4(t)\,dt$ you got $\frac{8-3\pi}{8}\,a^4$, but when i used the reduction formula for $sin^n x$ i did not get the constant 8. Can you explain why this happened?

Comment: @AyanShah: which reduction formula are you referring to? I just wrote $\sin^4(t)$ as $\frac{3}{8}-\frac{1}{2} \cos(2t)+\frac{1}{8}\cos(4t)$ and performed termwise integration.

Comment: @JackD'Aurizio [link](https://www.studypage.in/images/maths/calculus/integration-reduction-formula.png) . I used the 3rd result from this image. Is it the case that it only works for $pi/2$

Comment: @AyanShah: there is no particular reason for expecting it works for *any* integration range, I guess.

Comment: @Jack D'Aurizio Actually this is not the full problem that i meant to solve. It was "Show that $\int_c( (x-y)^3\,dx+(x-y)^3dy) = 3pi a^4$ taken along the circle $x^2 + y^2=a^2$ in counter clockwise direction. [page1](https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B1EPvdf6Gq6HQ2p1dDdiMkpaWmc) and [page2](https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B1EPvdf6Gq6HZFdxSUpzeWtpTUU) is my effort which was possible through your help. But somehow the answer that i am getting does not match with what is required to be shown.

Comment: @AyanShah: what about a change of variables? Maybe like $x+y = \sqrt{2} u,\; x-y=\sqrt{2} v$, leading to a straightforward integral? You over-complicated things by directly switching to polar coordinates, and incorrectly performed the change of coordinates.

Comment: @JackD'Aurizio I took the first quadrant of the circle and multiplied it by 4.

Comment: @AyanShah: that is a different, simpler problem and I think I helped enough here. I am willing to politely disengage.

Answer (score 0):

**HINTS:**

$$(x-y)^3=x^3-3x^2y+3xy^2-y^3$$

Use the substitution $x=a\sin(y)$ for the terms involving $\sqrt{a^2-x^2}$ and $(\sqrt{a^2-x^2})^3$.

Comment: Not yet. trying it now. Thanks

Comment: lease let me know how I can improve this answer too. As always, I really want to give you the best answer I can. If the answer was not useful, I am happy to delete it. -Mark

Answer (score 0):

Hint: Let $x=a\sin t$ then 
$$\int_0^a (x-(\sqrt{a^2-x^2}))^3dx=a^4\int_0^{\frac{\pi}{2}}(\sin t-\cos t)^3\cos t\,dt$$

Comment: Can you give me hints as to what i am to do after this. Integration by parts after expanding doesnot seem to be working

Comment: Uh. yes. Simplify integrand to $\sin t\cos t-\sin t\cos^3t-\cos2t-\frac14\cos4t-\frac34$.